# Add Module to SugarCRM ACL Role List Admin Page when Module doesn't exist?

Tags: php, acl, sugarcrm

I am developing a module for SUgarCRM that is not your typical module.

My main module shows up in the SugarCRM Role list of mOdules but my module has several **sub-modules** which are sections in my main module that have there own custom database table and do not have a module folder or Bean.

Because of this, these sections do not automatically show up on the SugarCRM ACL Role admin page.

I am hoping someone can tell me how to or if it is even possible to add non-real modules as modules in the ACL Role admin page?

I am hoping with code I can manually create some database records and run some code to make it work.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those sub-modules would still be considered modules/beans in Sugar. You just wouldn't have a visible tab for them. In the manifest.php you would define each of those in the beans array and set 'tab' => false for each of those that are a sub-module. The path would be set to a bean that correlates to your table.

```
'beans' =>
    array (
        array (
          'module' => 'MySubModule',
          'class' => 'MySubModule',
          'path' => 'modules/MySubModule/MySubModule.php',
          'tab' => false,
        ),
    ),
```

Comment: Hey Jason, are you sure they would be a Bean though being as they are DB tables I manually created and they do not extend the Bean class or anything?

Comment: The way they are being setup and used, I believe they are basically invissibble to SugarCRM as far as being a Bean.  If you misunderstood ( Id didn't explain well enough) then perhaps simple defining `define each of those in the beans array in the manifest.php` this doesn't make them become BEans by any chance does it?  Would be really cool if it is that simple but I have a feeling it might not in my situation

Comment: Yes, you can create a bean for any custom table that you manually created. That can be used both for permission purposes and for leveraging the SugarBean for doing queries, etc. A good example of a bare bones bean is in /modules/Contacts/ContactOpportunityRelationship.php. The key is to extend the SugarBean and define some fields such as the name of the database table.

Comment: Great, if I can get this working 100% maybe i'll post a detailed step by step example as I have not seen anything like this online!